# Obtain Parent of HyperLink In JS method when I click on HyperLink

Tags: javascript, asp.net, hyperlink

I have one `HyperLink`

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="link2" runat="server" 
                           NavigateUrl="javascript:MyMethod(this);" >
   Text
</asp:HyperLink>
```

on the the JS Method I want to receive this hyperlink

```
function MyMethod(item) {
//but parent of this item is window, but in html is li
                   debugger;
}
```

How to get the parent of this HyperLink on JS Method?

HTML In the page:

```
<li style="white-space: nowrap">
  <a id="ctl00_cphMain_ctl00_HyperLink2" href="javascript:MyMethod(this);">
                                                                Text Link</a>
  <input type="hidden" id="ctl00_cphMain_ctl00_id" 
                                  value="2g6e3c32-df3f-4533-sd3b-a99d6a79d9ea">
 </li>
```

Finally I want to get the value of hidden input, is the 2nd child of the li

Comment: HOW are you getting the parent? Show what you tried.

Comment: >item.parent
>Window {top: Window, window: Window, location: Location, external: Object, chrome: Object…}

Comment: @Andrei http://clip2net.com/s/idttdC

Comment: Paste the output HTML from the ASP page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the markup to

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="link2" runat="server" onclick ="MyMethod(this);" > Text
</asp:HyperLink>
```

Then you can access the parent element using `parentNode`

```
function MyMethod(item) {
 var parent = item.parentNode; 
}
```

Comment: try changing `<asp:HyperLink ID="link2" runat="server" onclick ="MyMethod(this);" >
   Text
</asp:HyperLink>` not much familiar with asp..